# Regex replace all qoutes between apostrophe's

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with javascript and classic asp, I am hoping someone can help me with this regex.

I need to replace

> " (quotes)

between apostrophe's with a regex.

I were thinking in the line of this, but this will replace the whole string with a quote?

```
textarea = textarea.replace(/\'.*?\'/ig, '&quote;');
```

Instead of having `'this is the text "click here"'` I need it to be

```
'this is the text "&quote;click here&quote;'
```

I any body can help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to turn your `.*?` into a capturing group by putting `()` around it.  Then in the replace method you can use `$1` to represent the first capturing group, `$2` to represent a second one, etc.  So, in other words, you would do:

```
textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerHTML
                             .replace(/'(.*?)"(.*?)"(.*?)'/g,
                                      "'$1&amp;quote;$2&amp;quote;$3'");
```

I assumed you wanted to replace the " with the word &quote; and not the character &quot;, but you can easily replace that if necessary.

[**Here's a working example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqFJ8/3/)

Comment: <textarea id="textarea">"this I do not want replaced", word word word 'this is the text "click here"'</textarea> as per yout example this is what the result should be <textarea id="textarea">"this I do not want replaced", word word word 'this is the text &quote;click here&quote;'</textarea>

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can't do this with a single regex and have it be foolproof.  The reason is that a regex can't keep track of state, so if your full string is something like

```
'"test"' "test" '"test"'
```

there's no way for the regex to know the 2nd quoted `test` shouldn't be replaced.

To do this, you need to first match `/'([^\']+)'/` and then do the replacement for all quotes inside each match `.replace/(\"/g, '&quot;')`

Comment: I am 100% sure that all the quotes are between 'this is the text "click here"' the apostrophe's

Comment: Actually, I don't think that it entirely correct. When you use regex to match the string in single quotes, it will check the first one and the third one - beacause the beginning of the second one is part of the first one, it won't be matched (man, that's one complicated explanation!).

Comment: I am writing an mysql insert statemet there is quotes outsite the string that I do not want to replace... I only want to replace the ones that is between the '    ' (two apostophe's) the ones outside I do not want to replace...

Comment: @Gerald, I hope you're not allowing the user to send (and _modify_) mysql queries with JavaScript!

Comment: You're right about needing two regexes. But the regex: `/'([^\']+)'/` above breaks if you have something like: `"That's not" 'like "MY" string!'`. My soultion will handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need more than one regex. Assuming that you don't want to handle escaped quotes, this tested function works on your test data:

```js
function process_data(text)
{ // Convert double quotes to HTML entity inside single quoted strings.
    var re_dsq = /("[^"]*")|('[^']*')/g;  // $1 = "string" or $2 = 'string'
    var re_dq = /"/g;                     // A  single "
    text = text.replace(re_dsq, function(m0, m1, m2) {
                if (m1) return m1;
                return m2.replace(re_dq, '&quot;');
            });
    return text;
}
```

If you do need to handle strings having escaped quotes, the regex can be easily modified.